# What NAnt editors are available?

Tags: editor, nant

I'm doing quite a bit of NAnt script writing at the moment and would love to know how I can speed the process up?

I'm currently editing the script in Visual Studio, then going to the command line to test the output. I like how Visual Studio can be configured to autocomplete your NAnt commands (via xsd) but I'm still testing my scripts on the command line.

Are there any tools that bring all of that together? I use Notepad++ quite a bit but would switch allegiance to another editor that has editing and command line functionality built in.

I guess what I'm looking for is something like NAnt Builder (http://www.nantbuilder.com) but I don't really want to spend that sort of money when I have my free current alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), it will handle this for you. And when you look at the overall value that the tool provides (almost any "favorite VS add-in" question on here lists ReSharper at the top), it is a pretty easy decision to go for it. [This link](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/nant_msbuild_script.html) provides a list of features.

A free alternative that requires some customization is [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Out of interest, can resharper run the targets of my build file? Thanks for the answer, I'll take a look and see what it can do!

Comment: Nope, I haven't seen that ability (but it would be nice). I edited my answer to include a link to the features that are supported.